# How to wrap a command which can handle a text object?

Tags: neovim, cursor-motions

The scenario is that the plugin I use (iron.nvim) has a mapping `crt` which handle text objects. Ultimately, this mapping is based on a command `<Plug>(iron-send-motion)`. I would like to create a new mapping based on it: `<localleader>sp` which is to apply `<Plug>(iron-send-motion)` on a paragraph -- since I use it often.

Is there a way that the existing command can be reused to tailor-make a new mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nmap` with your `<Plug>` mapping

```
nmap <localleader>sp <Plug>(iron-send-motion)ap
```

May need to add `<buffer>` option if this is `'filetype'` specific.

Comment: Thanks! It is a surprise to me that simply appending `ap` would work.